# Spark scala get an array of type string from multiple columns

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark, accumulator

I am using spark with scala.

Imagine the input:

[image]

I would like to know how to get the following output [see the column accumulator on the following image] which should be a **Array of type String Array[String]**

[image]

In my real dataframe I have more than 3 columns. I have several thousand of column.

How can I proceed in order to get my desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `array` function and map a sequence of columns:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, col, udf} 

val tmp = array(df.columns.map(c => when(col(c) =!= 0, c)):_*)
```

where

```
when(col(c) =!= 0, c)
```

takes a column name if column value is different than zero and null otherwise.

and use an UDF to filter nulls:

```
val dropNulls = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => xs.flatMap(Option(_)))
df.withColumn("accumulator", dropNulls(tmp))
```

So with example data:

```
val df = Seq((1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0)).toDF("apple", "orange", "kiwi")
```

you first get:

```
+-----+------+----+--------------------+
|apple|orange|kiwi|                 tmp|
+-----+------+----+--------------------+
|    1|     0|   1| [apple, null, kiwi]|
|    0|     1|   1|[null, orange, kiwi]|
|    1|     0|   0| [apple, null, null]|
+-----+------+----+--------------------+
```

and finally:

```
+-----+------+----+--------------+
|apple|orange|kiwi|   accumulator|
+-----+------+----+--------------+
|    1|     0|   1| [apple, kiwi]|
|    0|     1|   1|[orange, kiwi]|
|    1|     0|   0|       [apple]|
+-----+------+----+--------------+
```