# Dataframe transformation (data preparation) in apache spark scala

Tags: scala, join, apache-spark, multilabel-classification

Thanks to a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021282/spark-scala-get-an-array-of-type-string-from-multiple-columns), I managed from this input :

[image]

To get the accumulator output.

[image]

Now I am trying to get the following:

[image]

What would be the  best way to get the following table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to use the function **explode** in spark.

Comment: Why don't you include a code example?  that would be helpful for others looking for a solution.

Comment: @anthonybell I will, I planed to. I just need a bit of time. I do it ASAP. Thanks