# spark scala map column names to output arraytype column for values true

Tags: arrays, string, scala, apache-spark

How can I create column colMap of ArrayType[StringType] which value is Array with elements being strings matching names of the column which values were true?

I have such input DataFrame:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|col1 |col2 |col3 |
+-----+-----+-----+
|true |false|true |
|false|false|false|
|false|false|true |
+-----+-----+-----+
```

and I want to create such output DataFrame:

```
+-----+-----+-----+------------+
|col1 |col2 |col3 |colMap      |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+
|true |false|true |[col1, col3]|
|false|false|false|[]          |
|false|false|true |[col3]      |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+
```

EDIT:
I have found this duplicated question:

[Spark scala get an array of type string from multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40021282/spark-scala-get-an-array-of-type-string-from-multiple-columns)

but wonder if there is better way to achieve the output?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using UDF to filter `null` values from an array, you can use built-in higher order function [filter](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter).

```
val df = Seq((true, false, true),
    (false, false, false),
    (false, false, true)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")


df.withColumn("colMap", array(df.columns.map(c=> when(col(c) === "true", c)):_*))
  .withColumn("colMap", expr("filter(colMap, c-> c is not null)"))
  .show(false)

+-----+-----+-----+------------+
|col1 |col2 |col3 |colMap      |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+
|true |false|true |[col1, col3]|
|false|false|false|[]          |
|false|false|true |[col3]      |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+
```